# AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'evaluate'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, opennlp

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
import numpy as np

frames=[singleteamone_tweets,singleteamtwo_tweets,twoteam_tweets]
All_data = pd.concat(frames)

#creating a bag of words model
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv= CountVectorizer()
X=cv.fit_transform(All_data.iloc[:,0]).toarray()  #.iloc[:,0]
Y=All_data.iloc[:,1].values


#training and test dataset

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

#Reshape 
#X_train = np.random.rand(3, 4)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))





classifier=Sequential()
#LSTM layers and Dropout regularization
classifier.add(LSTM(units=30,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

classifier.add(LSTM(units=30,return_sequences=True))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

classifier.add(LSTM(units=30,return_sequences=True))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

classifier.add(LSTM(units=30))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

#output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
```

I am getting an error while checking the accuracy its showing attribute error :- history object has no attribute ' evaluate'. i tried to fix this nothing it working.AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'evaluate'

#compiling the RNN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

```
model=classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=30,batch_size=15)



# Final evaluation of the model

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test)
```

Comment: It will be helpful for others to understand the issue if you include the error stack trace.

Comment: Did you try `test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)` ? I think this is the problem. You need to give Y_test  to the function

Comment: I tried but its showing error. ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (155, 1101). how will I solve this error!

Answer (score 2):

You should instead do something like this-

```py
history = model.fit(...)
```

According to Keras documentation, the `model.fit` method returns a History callback, which has a history attribute containing the lists of successive losses and other metrics.

`history` has no attribute called 'evaluate' you should instead do this to get the validation accuracies. `evaluate` is an attribute of the `model` object.

```py
history.history['accuracy']
```

This returns you a list of the epoch wise training accuracy.

To find your final test accuracy you should use the `evaluate` attribute on the `model` object-

> You also need to give it `y_test` as you are trying to calculate the
> accuracy.

```py
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

# This could also be a generator instead
# model.evaluate(test_generator)
```

The above piece of code

Quoted from [`evaluate()` method documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate):

> Returns
>
> Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and no metrics) or
> list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics).
> The attribute model.metrics_names will give you the display labels for
> the scalar outputs.

Therefore, you can use `metrics_names` property of your model to find out what each of those values corresponds to. For example, if you write:

```py
print(model.metrics_names)
```

This gives you the names of all the metrics. Since you need `accuracy` if you compile the model with-

```py
metrics=["accuracy"]
```

You would also receive the accuracy in the `model.evaluate()` output.

Comment: I tried what you said but its showing error . ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (155, 1101). this is what I'm getting . How will I solve this!

Comment: when i am trying to run this line  i am getting dimension error. test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test).  the error is ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (155, 1101)

Comment: test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
It does not work always, I have now edited the post to include details about this too.

Comment: so how we will calculate then any idea?

Comment: I have edited the post to include details about that

Answer (score 0):

## It should work

history=classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=30,batch_size=15)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).